# cakephp advance configuration error

Tags: configuration, file-permissions, permission-denied

i have an aplication in cakephp, i want to move the 'lib' directory to '/usr/lib' (im on debian wheezy). But i configure in 'index.php' (app/webroot/index.php) the path throws this error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Can't find application core file. Please create /var/www/tlfmovil/app/Config/core.php, and make sure it is readable by PHP. in /usr/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 79, referer: http://telefonia.cnti.gob.ve/usuarios
```

this is the path i defined in index.php:

```
 if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
       define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'usr' . DS . 'lib');
   }
```

note: i put 777 permissions on mi cakephp app (/var/www/tlfmovil/) and in /usr/lib/Cake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem... i copied the original 'lib/Cake' directory and its works